# How should I chose between _mm_move_sd / _mm_shuffle_pd / _mm_blend_pd

Tags: x86, simd

If I am not mistaken,

```
_mm_shuffle_pd(x, y, _MM_SHUFFLE2(0, 1));
```

and

```
_mm_move_sd(x, y);
```

And also `_mm_blend_pd` in a later instruction set should all do the same thing.

But clang and gcc generate different instructions on sse2 [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/W9rPvvYzo).
And they replace movps with blend if sse4.2 is avaliable [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/jjaMP5sT3)

Is there a reason I should choose one over the other?

Comment: Those two statements don't do the same thing.  The low half of `_mm_move_sd`'s output comes from its second operand, high half from the first, opposite of `_mm_shuffle_pd(x,y, int)`.  (I made test callers that passed constants to check what if any different there might be since I didn't spot that from just looking at them: https://godbolt.org/z/3nqjdnroK clang helpfully prints comments showing the values after constant-propagation.)  If they were identical shuffles, then yeah clang's shuffle optimizer would almost certainly have made the same asm, so I suspected they weren't.

Comment: But they are the same, you just might need to change the order of operands. Look, just movsd twice: https://godbolt.org/z/P8MK38vEs

Comment: To make them identical (https://godbolt.org/z/qh9Ex67oa), I also needed to change the shuffle constant.  So `movsd x,y` and `_mm_shuffle_pd(y, x, _MM_SHUFFLE2(0, 1));`  Then clang uses its preferred `shufps` in both cases, and GCC uses `movsd` in both cases.  Both ways are the same machine-code size, and `movsd` would be faster on ancient CPUs like Conroe where the shuffle unit is only 64-bit wide (but 64-bit granularity shuffles have no problem.)
Did you check https://uops.info/ and check their throughputs on various CPUs that are relevant for `-mtune=generic`?

Comment: Oh cool, clang's shuffle optimizer takes into account avoiding a `movaps` register-copy, using `movsd` or `shufps` so XMM0 (first arg and return value) can be the destination.

Comment: Immediate blends are very cheap; IDK why `movsd x,x` still decodes to a shuffle uop for port 5 only, instead of a `blendpd` uop, on CPUs like Nehalem or Skylake.  Compilers are generally correct to favour them.  It looks like Ice Lake finally got around to optimizing `movsd x,x` into 1 uop for any of p015.  Zen runs it on any vector ALU port.

Comment: Why did they need a new instruction instead of making `_mm_shuffle_pd` better?

Comment: `movsd` and `shufpd` were both introduced in SSE2.  IDK why `movsd xmm,xmm` is a merge instead of a zero-extending move like SSE2 `movq`, since `shufpd` can already do that rarely-needed merging.  Probably for consistency with the SSE1 design choice for `movss x,x` being a merge, but a load zero-extending.  On PIII and Pentium-M with 64-bit SIMD execution units, `movss` was 1 uop but `movaps` was 2, since it writes the high half.  AMD K8 is the same.

Comment: (IDK if compilers at the time ever generated scalar code using `movss` instead of `movaps`, suffering a false dependency which even future CPUs wouldn't avoid, in exchange for better throughput.  Probably not since P6 family had register-read stalls for "cold" registers, the ones you'd want to pick for a move destination to make the output dependency not a problem.)

Comment: As for why `shufpd` doesn't use two 2-bit fields that select from all 4 elements across 2 registers, instead of its current design of two 1-bit fields where the low element selects from within the first reg, and second selects within the second, that's the same pattern of data movement as `shufps`.  That's not a very good argument, but Intel's ISA design at the time often seemed poorly thought out, or just to simplify decoding, like `movhpd` being the same as `movhps`, but it's just a prefix in front of the same opcode.

Comment: Also, actual reasons, it takes fewer wires and transistors if each output bit only has to pick from 2 possible input bits, instead of from any of 4 bits across 4 elements of 2x 128-bit inputs.  Making `shufpd` more powerful would have cost more transistors, and probably more important, more wires crossing each other in a tight space.

Comment: I was trying to remember where I'd recently written about shuffles that can only pick elements from one vector for part of the output.  Just found it: [AV512: Best way to combine horizontal sum and broadcast](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76402515) - `vshuff64x2 z,z,z,imm8` (128-bit shuffle granularity) is like `shufps` in how the immediate is used.  And there are cases where you'd expect CPUs to run a shuffle like `vpermilpd` at least as efficiently as `vshufpd` (e.g. duplicating the input and feeding the same immediate), but no, on Ice Lake it runs on fewer ports.